# Why can't I UrlFetchApp to my on premise server behind Dynamic DNS from Goolge Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

Trying
`UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`
from Google Apps Script.

Is not wroking when I try to connect to my on premise server behind a Dynamic DNS.
I'm using No-ip.com.
If I try the same request using Postman it works perfectly.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Exception: Address unavailable

Comment: When I go to their site, it is down. Example: https://www.noip.com/plusdns/ Only their support URLs work.